# How to paste a smiley () within Pages or Keynote?

Tags: pages, font, keynote, emoji

Within the `Character viewer`, selecting the `Emoji` font set, I can paste a smiley here: . I can do exactly the same paste of a smiley within TextEdit.

When I try to paste the same symbol within a `Pages` or `Keynote` document, I only see an area of white space which is inserted. This invisible character is in `Apple  Color  Emoji`, `Regular`, `12` points font.

I noticed the same behaviour on `Mountain Lion`, `Mavericks` and `Yosemite`, on 3 different Macs. Hence I diagnose this isn't an accidental corruption of a font sets and this isn't an accidental bug within one version of MacOS X.

The problem might be within the way these characters are displayed within many versions of MacOS X.

I read this *long* discussion on Apple discussion groups [Emoji in Pages](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3205972?tstart=0). But this discussion, as usual, doesn't create a conclusion or a solution (Tom Gewecke's analysis is the only interesting point).

---

I am running MacOS X, from any version between 10.7 to 10.10.

I am running `Pages 4.3`, `Keynote 5.3`.

How may one insert a smiley in a `Pages` or `Keynote` document?

Answer (score 2):

Emoji simply wasn't supported in Pages 4.3 or Keynote 5.3

Our very own fonts guru, Tom Gewecke mentions such in https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4025411?start=0&tstart=0

The 'fix' is to update, I'm afraid.
It works perfectly well in Pages 5.6.1 & Keynote 6.6.1